# pop up window in jquery, retain inserted values

Tags: jquery

I have this homework saying:

"Write a web page which contains a form with at least five input fields and a button. If the user clicks on that button a modal interface window (actually a div) should pop out in the center of the browser window. This modal window should contain 4 input fields and a button. If the user clicks on that button, the modal window disappears and all the values inserted by the user in the modal window's input fields will be concatenated and added to a text field in the main form. During the time the modal window is displayed, the fields from the main form will be inactive and a transparrent gray div should be displayed on top of the web page (this grey div should be beneath the modal window and should occupy the whole browser window)."

All I did until now is the first part. I can't retain the values inserted and append them to a text field. What I have until now is:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
  <title>Modal Login Window Demo</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://designshack.net/favicon.ico">
  <link rel="icon" href="http://designshack.net/favicon.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="style.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"  src="js/jquery.leanModal.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="w">
    <div id="content">
        <form id="myform">
            <label for="username">First name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname">
            <label for="username">Last name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname">
            <label for="username">Address:</label>
            <input type="text" name="address" id="address">
            <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle1" value="Bike">I have a bike<br>
            <input type="radio" name="like" value="like">Like this page?<br>
            <center><a href="#loginmodal" class="flatbtn" id="modaltrigger">Open window</a></center>
        </form>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="loginmodal" style="display:none;">
    <h1>So my window just showed up!</h1>
    <form id="loginform" name="loginform" method="post" action="index.html">
        <label for="username">First name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname">
        <label for="username">Last name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname">
        <label for="username">Address:</label>
        <input type="text" name="address" id="address">
        <label for="username">Description:</label>
        <input type="text" name="description" id="description">
       <div class="center"><input type="submit" name="loginbtn" id="loginbtn" class="flatbtn-blu hidemodal" value="Close window" tabindex="3">    </div>
    </form>
  </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
    $('#loginform').submit(function(e){
    return false;
  });

  $('#modaltrigger').leanModal({ top: 110, overlay: 0.45, closeButton: ".hidemodal" });
});

var val1 = $("#firstnamemodal").val();
var val2 = $("#lastnamemodal").val();
var val3 = $("#addressmodal").val();
var val4 = $("#descriptionmodal").val();

var concatenatedValue = val1 + val2 + val3 + val4;

$("#loginbtn").click(function() {
    $("#firstname").val(concatenatedValue);
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the first part only works. after I insert values and close the popup window nothing hapens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you have conflicting ID names. Only one element can ever carry the same ID on a page. So, rename the IDs in the modal window to something like *firstnamemodal*, *lastnamemodal*, and so on.

From what I understand, you want to retrieve the value from the 4 input fields (of the modal window), and place them together into one string, and attach that string to one of the other 5 existing fields. Well, to do so we first need to retrieve the values of those 4 input fields seperately. This can be done with

```
var val1 = $("#firstnamemodal").val();
var val2 = $("#lastnamemodal").val();
var val3 = $("#addressmodal").val();
var val4 = $("#descriptionmodal").val();
```

Then, concatenating these is simply done with

```
var concatenatedValue = val1 + val2 + val3 + val4;
```

Then, to add these to a certain input field (let's say the first one), use:

```
$("#loginbtn").click(function() {
    $("#firstname").val(concatenatedValue);
});
```

So, the full code becomes

```
$("#loginbtn").click(function() {
    var val1 = $("#firstnamemodal").val();
    var val2 = $("#lastnamemodal").val();
    var val3 = $("#addressmodal").val();
    var val4 = $("#descriptionmodal").val();
    var concatenatedValue = val1 + val2 + val3 + val4;
    $("#firstname").val(concatenatedValue);
});
```

Comment: I inserted the code, but nothing happens. I mean, I insert the values in the pop up window, but when I close it nothing happens.

Comment: Did you place all code within the click event? (Forgot to mention it, included full code now) Did you rename the IDs?

Comment: Yes, I changed the ids but I did not insert the code within the click event. Now it works perfectly. Thank you so much.